# Sound Card not detected in Ubuntu 14.04 - Laptop HP 15-AY112NE

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I am new to Ubuntu.
I installed on the newly bought laptop HP 15-AYN112NE, UBUNTU 14.04 on top of FREEDOS.

Installation is ok, but no sound is heard at all.
Sound is UN-MUTED.

I follow the TS Guide:

[HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingGuide)

No Soudcards Found as result from aplay -l

```
zico@zico-HP-Notebook:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
zico@zico-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for zico: 
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
zico@zico-HP-Notebook:~$ echo "Sound cards recognized by the system:"; lspci -nn | grep --color=none '\[04[80][13]\]'; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel modules: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel drivers in use: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done
Sound cards recognized by the system:
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
Sound cards recognized by ALSA:
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
zico@zico-HP-Notebook:~$ uname -r
3.19.0-25-generic


$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libasound2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 428 not upgraded.
Need to get 324 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libasound2 i386 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7 [324 kB]
Fetched 324 kB in 2s (129 kB/s)                         
(Reading database ... 167330 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libasound2_1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libasound2:i386 (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) over (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Setting up libasound2:i386 (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```